# Ускоряют ли хуки wordpress работу функций?

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Ускоряют ли хуки работу функции ? или на скорость это никак не сказывается ?)
Для примера:

```
function echo_1( $data ){
    echo $data[0] .' '. $data[1] .'!';
}
add_action( 'my_hook', 'echo_1' );

do_action( 'my_hook', [ 'Привет', ' мир' ] );
```

Что быстрее отработает ?
вызов `echo_1($data);`
или `do_action( 'my_hook', [ 'Привет', ' мир' ] );` ? или разницы в скорости вообще нет ?)

Comment: Если хотите что бы работало быстро, не используйте wordpress. имхо

Comment: Естественно, хуки добавляют определенную нагрузку - do_action лезет в таблицу хуков, находит там my_hook, вызывает оттуда  все зарегистрированные фукнции типа echo_1, а уж эта функция вызовет echo. Но код хуков настолько оптимизирован, что заметить разницу можно только при тысячах вызовов. И как справедливо заметил SeVlad, хуки не для ускорения.

Answer (score 3):

Хуки не для "ускорения", а для расширения/изменения функционала.

> Что быстрее отработает ? вызов `echo_1($data);` или `do_action( 'my_hook', [ 'Привет', ' мир' ] );` ? или разницы в скорости вообще нет
> ?)

С чистым php как правило будет быстрее. Но насколько [медных полушек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0) - вопрос в конкретном применении.

Comment: Я Вас понял, спасибо за ответ )